# Ubuntu 18.04 does not recognize the android smartphone by usb cable connection

Tags: 18.04, usb, android, mtp

I use ubuntu 18.04 and android 8.0.0 in a Moto Z2 Play.
What I've tried:
1 - I reinstalled the mtp-tools package.
2- Check if the android is configured for USB MPT connection in the developer options of the smartphone.
3- I installed android-file-transfer
4- I tried installing
with the smartphone connected in the USB I receive in response to the commands:

lsubs:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087: 8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087: 07dc Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf: 28b4 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 138a: 0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b: 0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

mtp-detect:

```
libmtp version: 1.1.13
Listing raw device (s)
     No raw devices found.
```

Battery charging is operating normally.

Comment: Try another cable.

Comment: I do not believe!!! lol
It's so simple! and I spent hours trying a solution, I just switched the smartphone, without thinking about the cable.
Thank you @GabrielaGarcia.